# Android ShareActionProvider with popup menu - undesired duplicate list

Tags: android, android-listview, shareactionprovider

Okay this is a pretty specific one: My ShareActionProvider is being used on posts in a forum. It works (apart from pesky facebook but I understand that is a well-known issue). However, when I select the share option from my pop-up menu, two lists are drawn, one on top of the other.

How can I fix it so only one list is displayed?

Edit: At least two other questions exist on SO referring to this problem:

[I Use ShareActionProvider in PopupMenu, but show two PopupMenu？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966542/i-use-shareactionprovider-in-popupmenu-but-show-two-popupmenu)

[Call ShareActionProvider from a PopupMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609773/call-shareactionprovider-from-a-popupmenu)

Here is my code:
Menu item in xml

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_community_overflow_share"
    android:title="@string/menu_share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Java

```
    private void share(MenuItem item) {
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's a message originally posted by " + mClickedMessage.getFirstName()
            + " " + mClickedMessage.getLastName() + ": " + mClickedMessage.getTheMessage() + "\n\n");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    setShareIntent(sendIntent);
}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

And here are some images:
Share list is first created
[image: Share list is first created]

When See All is clicked

[image: When See All is clicked]

When list is scrolled

[image: When list is scrolled]

Hopefully the problem is clear. Also note the icons cannot be clicked, doing so behaves like a click outside the list all together and kills it.

Comment: Okay I am now certain two lists are drawing on top of one another and will change the title of the question to reflect this, can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you doing anything in `onOptionsItemSelected()`?

Comment: Wow totally forgot about this one :) onOptionsItemSelected() was being used for the actionbar options (you can see the little pencil in the image) - Post Message, and also logout / settings overflow items. I wanted to keep these separate to each forum message context menu. I will post the current code I am using as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I eventually went with (I'm not even sure how I figured it out as it was a long time ago), but it might help someone.

The solution was not ideal, it removes the duplicate list, but leaves behind the boring list (without icons), and I kind of wanted the other one. If I recall this method of sharing is outdated and it would be excellent if someone could shed more light on the issue.

```
private void share(MenuItem item) {
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's a message originally posted by " + mClickedMessage.getFirstName()
                + " " + mClickedMessage.getLastName() + ": " + mClickedMessage.getTheMessage() + "\n\n Sent via Loylap");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_post_to)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with my own solution that basically replaces ShareActionProvider with a new class that gets the same Activites with the same intent filter, called [ShareActionAdapter](https://gist.github.com/nathanjsweet/fc71131f2d8ce96d9804#file-shareactionadapter-java). The relevant snippet is as follows though:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
 m_list = new ArrayList<>(pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER));
```

The full gist that mimics a the popup experience can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nathanjsweet/fc71131f2d8ce96d9804)